# Does iOS devices deletes images picked by ImagePicker (Flutter) over time?

Tags: ios, flutter, imagepicker

I have a Flutter application that uploads pictures with image Picker and keeps track of the file path until the user connects to the internet and synchronize it, however some iOS users found that the images picked by Image Picker are deleted (No such file or Directoty), does this usually happen and the cache might be removed by time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documentation of `image_picker` says:

```
Images and videos picked using the camera are saved to your application's
local cache, and should therefore be expected to only be around temporarily.
If you require your picked image to be stored permanently,
it is your responsibility to move it to a more permanent location.
```